# List and Single-Variable in View-Specific Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a page where users can search for a specific school, then view their search results. As such, I think I need a view-specific model that includes both a list of entities as well as a single entity (for the search term). The error I'm encountering is that "DashboardViewModel contains no definition for listschools..."

I've created model as such:

```
 public class DashboardViewModel
{
[Display(Name = "University Name")]
public string name { get; set; }

public List<SchoolViewModel> listschools { get; set; }
}

 public class SchoolViewModel
{
public string instnm { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to accesss both elements in the view as follows, after declaring the model with "@model DashboardViewModel":

```
  <table>
            @foreach (var u in Model.listschools)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       @u.instnm
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
</table>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name, new { })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually best to reference the namespace to the ViewModel in the View declaration:

```
@{
    @model Your.Namespace.DashboardViewModel
}
```

in case you have another ViewModel of the same name being referenced by mistake,

and to make sure the List is populated by the Controller (using the same reference to the ViewModel in question)